# How to play COD: BO & COD: BO2 again with higher difficulty level?

Tags: xbox-360, call-of-duty-black-ops, call-of-duty-black-ops-2

I completed the game, a while ago, on the easiest setting. Now, how do I play again at a higher setting. I don't see it in the menu. I really want to try with regular. I mean this mainly for CODBO2. Does it appear if I try it on a different memory slot?

Comment: ? I don't think you mean "memory slot" on an Xbox-360. But you should be able to change it in the options. If you can't, you can also change it in when you choose a level, or start a new campaign.

Comment: Did you try starting a new campaign? There you should have an option to increase difficulty

Comment: @Novarg I said that allready.

Comment: I made it work. I'm an idiot. I just signed in with a different profile and it let me. God, I feel forking stupid.

Answer (score 2):

at menu screen for campaign, goto settings/options and then game, the Difficulty setting should be there. If not. try loading the game from the beggining. just as you start playing the first level press start and goto options/setting from there. once again, goto Game. and then you should see the Difficulty setting.

Comment: Thanks. Your advice worked. I did it in a new memory slot.